# EXC Bad Instruction Error Swift

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-instruction

I have an issue where I click on a tableviewcell and it is supposed to populate a detail view controller but when I click the cell this error pops up.

```
import UIKit
import Former
import Parse
import MapKit
import Material
import CoreLocation

class EventDetailViewController: FormViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

// MARK: Public

var event: PFObject?
var organizer: PFUser?
var currentUserStatus = 2
var confirmedUsers = [PFObject]()
var maybeUsers = [PFObject]()
var invitedUsers = [PFObject]()
var confirmedUserIDs = [String]()
var maybeUserIDs = [String]()
var invitedUserIDSs = [String]()

// MARK: Public

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure UI
    title = "Event Details"
    tableView.contentInset.top = 0
    tableView.contentInset.bottom = 30

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: Icon.cm.close, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelButtonPressed))

    organizer = event?.object(forKey: PF_EVENTS_ORGANIZER) as? PFUser
    organizer!.fetchInBackground { (user: PFObject?, error: Error?) in
        if error == nil {
            self.insertEventDetail()
            for pointer in (self.event?.object(forKey: PF_EVENTS_CONFIRMED) as! [PFUser]) {
                pointer.fetchInBackground(block: { (user: PFObject?, error: Error?) in
                    if error == nil {
                        if user?.objectId == PFUser.current()?.objectId {
                            self.currentUserStatus = 0
                            self.choiceRow.configure(handler: {
                                $0.selectedIndex = self.currentUserStatus
                            })
                        }
                        self.confirmedUsers.append(user!)
                        self.confirmedUserIDs.append(user!.objectId!)

                        if pointer == (self.event?.object(forKey: PF_EVENTS_CONFIRMED) as! [PFUser]).last {
                            // All users have been downloaded
                            self.insertUsers(users: self.confirmedUsers, header: "Going", section: 2)
                            if self.currentUserStatus == 0 {
                                self.former.insertUpdate(rowFormer: self.newRow, toIndexPath: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 2), rowAnimation: .fade)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            for pointer in (self.event?.object(forKey: PF_EVENTS_MAYBE) as! [PFUser]) {
                pointer.fetchInBackground(block: { (user: PFObject?, error: Error?) in
                    if error == nil {
                        if user?.objectId == PFUser.current()?.objectId {
                            self.currentUserStatus = 1
                            self.choiceRow.configure(handler: {
                                $0.selectedIndex = self.currentUserStatus
                            })
                        }
                        self.maybeUsers.append(user!)
                        self.maybeUserIDs.append(user!.objectId!)

                        if pointer == (self.event?.object(forKey: PF_EVENTS_MAYBE) as! [PFUser]).last {
                            // All users have been downloaded
                            var section = 3
                            if self.former.sectionFormers.count < 2 {
                                section = 2
                            }
                            self.insertUsers(users: self.maybeUsers, header: "Maybe", section: section)
                            if self.currentUserStatus == 1 {
                                self.former.insertUpdate(rowFormer: self.newRow, toIndexPath: IndexPath(row: 0, section: section), rowAnimation: .fade)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            for pointer in (self.event?.object(forKey: PF_EVENTS_INVITE_TO) as! [PFUser]) {
                pointer.fetchInBackground(block: { (user: PFObject?, error: Error?) in
                    if error == nil {
                        self.invitedUsers.append(user!)
                        if pointer == (self.event?.object(forKey: PF_EVENTS_INVITE_TO) as! [PFUser]).last {
                            // All users have been downloaded
                            var section = 4
                            if self.former.sectionFormers.count == 2 {
                                section = 3
                            } else if self.former.sectionFormers.count < 2 {
                                section = 2
                            }
                            self.insertUsers(users: self.invitedUsers, header: "Invited", section: section)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            if (self.event?.object(forKey: PF_EVENTS_CONFIRMED) as! [PFUser]).count == 0 {
                self.insertEmpty(header: "Confirmed")
            }
            if (self.event?.object(forKey: PF_EVENTS_MAYBE) as! [PFUser]).count == 0 {
                self.insertEmpty(header: "Maybe")
            }
            if (self.event?.object(forKey: PF_EVENTS_INVITE_TO) as! [PFUser]).count == 0 {
                self.insertEmpty(header: "Invited")
            }
        }
    }

    if organizer?.objectId == PFUser.current()?.objectId {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: Icon.cm.edit, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editButtonPressed))
    }
}

// MARK: Private

private func insertUsers(users: [PFObject], header: String, section: Int) {
    var userRows = [LabelRowFormer<ProfileImageCell>]()
    for user in users {
        if user.objectId != PFUser.current()?.objectId {
            userRows.append(LabelRowFormer<ProfileImageCell>(instantiateType: .Nib(nibName: "ProfileImageCell")) {
                $0.iconView.backgroundColor = MAIN_COLOR
                $0.iconView.layer.borderWidth = 1
                $0.iconView.layer.borderColor = MAIN_COLOR?.cgColor
                $0.iconView.image = UIImage(named: "profile_blank")
                $0.iconView.file = user[PF_USER_PICTURE] as? PFFile
                $0.iconView.loadInBackground()
                $0.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
                }.configure {
                    $0.text = user[PF_USER_FULLNAME] as? String
                    $0.rowHeight = 60
                }.onSelected { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.former.deselect(animated: true)
                    let profileVC = PublicProfileViewController()
                    profileVC.user = user
                    self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileVC, animated: true)
            })
        }
    }
    self.former.insert(sectionFormer: (sectionFormer: SectionFormer(rowFormers: userRows).set(headerViewFormer: TableFunctions.createHeader(text: header))) as! SectionFormer, toSection: section)
    self.former.reload()
}

private func insertEmpty(header: String) {
    let zeroRow = LabelRowFormer<ImageCell>(instantiateType: .Nib(nibName: "ImageCell")) { _ in
        }.configure {
            $0.rowHeight = 0
    }
```

Below is where that Code gives me an EXC Bad Instruction

```
self.former.append(sectionFormer: (sectionFormer: SectionFormer(rowFormer: zeroRow).set(headerViewFormer: TableFunctions.createHeader(text: header))) as! SectionFormer)
 self.former.reload()
}
```

Comment: There can be two cases : 1. either you are editing your datasource when it is not available in memory.
2.Does Append function works fine if you remains on table view & not moving to detail view?